# How to Structure a Series of Books? Can the Hero's Journey be Used?

Tags: plot, structure, series, plot-structure

I'm working on a franchise universe that will form the base for a wide range of interconnected stories told via different media. I plan to loosely base each separate storyline on the concept of the *Hero's Journey*, but I've recently started to wonder how to structure the overarching developments across the different books. Can the *Hero's Journey* also be used on a meta-level? Would this even make sense? Are there any other ideas on how to structure a series of books or a multi-volume storyline?

Note that I'm not looking for software suggestions, but for help with structuring the overarching narrative. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer

A franchise universe is a setting and as such doesn't have a narrative structure. There may be historical developments similar to the history of the real world. This history may interact with the narratives that take place in it.

The Hero's Journey is a story template that only applies to one specific type of story: that of a single hero.

You can build a franchise universe around the story of a hero. This will mean that every aspect in every story told in that universe will be in relation to the journey of that hero. This means that that hero must be of central importance to that universe and that his fate must touch upon every small aspect of it.

The Star Wars universe can be interpreted in this way. Every story that has been told there is ultimately governed by the story of Luke Skywalker and dependent on it.

But typically fictional universes aren't written that way. The stories set in most fictional worlds only share a common setting and either don't bear on each other at all or only in relation to the shared history of that setting, much like events in the real world, but not in relation to a common mythical hero. Examples are the [Alliance-Union universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliance%E2%80%93Union_universe) of C. J. Cherryh, that is structured around a common political history, or Tolkien's Middle-earth, where all stories are governed by the mythical creation of the world and the beings in it. Not every story set in Tolkien's Middle-earth has to do with Sauron and the Ring, but all stories follow from the mythical structure of the world that Illuvatar has created and the systemic relations among the different kinds of beings within that creation myth.

Every other worldbuilding principle can govern your franchise universe. For example, Doris Lessing's *Canopus in Argos* was created around social questions that the author wanted to explore.

---

**Clarification of Terminology in Preparation for the Answer Given Above**

First, let's try and understand what a series and a franchise universe are:

- A **standalone novel** is a book that can be read on its own; the reader doesn't have to be familiar with other books to understand and fully appreciate its story.
- A **multi-volume work** is a story that is told in a limited, predefined number of separately published books, e.g. a trilogy or a duology or a pentalogy; the reader will have to start at volume one and read all the way to the end of the last volume to make sense of the story.
- An **open-ended series** is a sequence of novels that all feature the same characters or take place in the same setting or follow some other connecting principle.
- A **franchise universe** is a setting for different kinds of works, from narrative works such as novels or movies to toys or non-fiction.

Please note that the word *series* is often used to refer to what I call multi-volume works. The "original Star Wars series" is a multi-volume work in my sense: the number of films was predefined before the first film was published, and the story develops over several films, all of which a viewer has to watch to understand the whole story.

* * *

Second, let's try and understand what the typical plot structure of those different kinds works is:

- The narrative arc in a standalone novel spans the enire volume and ends at its end.
- The narrative of a multi-volume work, such as a trilogy, spans all volumes of that work. A multi-volume work can be thought of as a novel that was too long to be printed in a single volume. Apart from being long and spread over multiple printed books, it does not differ from a standalone novel and has the same kind of internal structure.
  The parts, "books", chapters, scenes of both the multi-volume work and the standalone novel have smaller arcs, as well. But the main arc spans the whole work in both cases.
- The individual volumes in an open-ended series all have their own arc, just like a standalone novel. Sometimes there is some development over the course of the volumes of the series, but often enough there isn't.
  In open-ended series such as Enid Blython's *Famous Five*, there is almost no character development between books and there are no fundamental changes in the cast, their relationships, the setting and so on. The reason for this is that the books are published over a long period of time, sometimes decades, where not all books are always available to a new reader, and anyone should be able to start anywhere in the series and read the books in every potential order. Donald Duck remains unhappily in love with Daisy and takes care of his nephews who haven't grown older for many decades now. Short story series published in magazines usually work the same, because not every reader will have read previous installments. Changes in open-ended series are most often caused by the changing generations of readers and their changing tastes, and less by any demands of the stories themselves.
- A franchise universe isn't primarily a story at all. It is a setting, and as such doesn't have a narrative arc. There may be "historic" developments and an interplay between the "history" of that universe and the stories told in it.

* * *

Third, let's try an understand what the *Hero's Journey* is:

The Hero's Journey is a structure that one writer (not a scholar) claims to have found in a specific type of story (not all stories) that tells of a hero who goes on an adventure, is victorious in a decisive crisis, and comes home changed or transformed.

The Hero's Journey isn't:

- the one and only structure found in all narratives; for example, love stories don't typically follow the Hero's Journey and utopias don't either;
- the actual structure of myths; folklorists have long criticized Campbell for projecting psychoanalytical theories into folklore, instead of actually analyzing it.

---

A note

Narrative *franchises* aren't usually planned. They happen. All the attempts that I have witnessed, where creative teams set out to create a franchise universe from the beginning, have ultimately failed. Because none of their stories attracted enough readers (or viewers), and none of the many other planned stories were ever told.

Neither George Lucas nor J. R. R. Tolkien have begun by setting out to create a franchise. The one created a world as a pastime beside his scholarly work; the other wanted to make the next movie after he had already made a few. The franchise grew much later from the unexpected success of their work.

My advice is that you try and write a good story. If it becomes a bestseller, you can always expand the storyline or the world and find new stories to tell in that universe. It's not that difficult. And maybe you are lucky and your story gets turned into a movie or a tv series and *becomes* a franchise.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive reply. You bring up a lot of interesting thoughts that I find immensely helpful. (Thanks for mentioning _Canopus in Argos_, by the way... I hadn't known this series.) Just as a clarification: I know, of course, that a franchise universe is not a "story" per se. I started out having a simple narrative in mind, then wanted to conceive a universe to have some kind of foundational structure and now plan to expand on this universe to contain different storylines. However, my universe is still built on a single societal development that I would like to explore.

Answer (score 1):

The Hero's Journey is just a template that people found a lot of stories following. And as I'm sure you know, that the framework has the hero not only go on a journey, but learn and grow internally as a person.

Technically, you could have multiple stories following different heroes and have an overarching story revolving around one. However, there is a problem. The hero's journey is a pretty strict formula and after a few episodes your audience could get bored.

It's also a good thing to note that a large, overarching arching story following the Hero's Journey has already been done in Star Wars. So well in fact that whenever I read something styled with the hero's journey, I always end up thinking how Star Wars did it better.

The best advice I've heard for writing templates like the Hero's Journey is not to use them directly when creating a story, but when something in your story is broke, look at what point you are in the Hero's Journey or whatever template is closest, and try to use it to fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughs, very helpful! Indeed, It also occurred to me that Star Wars had an overarching Hero's Journey, but I wasn't aware that large multi-volume Hero's Journeys seems to be the exception rather than the rule. I wonder, though, if it would be possible to identify some other kind of overarching structure in series like, say, Harry Potter or the Hunger Games...